# Why does this custom file field uploaded on profile not download from the emailed link?

Tags: wordpress, profile, custom-fields, email, forms

I created a **custom profile** (to use as a form on my website) with a custom **file field**...When the user fills out the form, they upload a file, and the form is sent to the admin email address. When I open the email and download the attached file, I am unable to open it; the file becomes corrupt. However, if I use FTP and navigate to ".../files/civicrm/custom" and download the file from there, the file opens and is not corrupt.

The website is using wordpress.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "corrupt" - what's the content of the file before and after upload? Try comparing the file you've uploaded and downloaded - are they the same size, same content ... ?

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you are closing the file properly before attaching to the email - any file which is open and been attached to email will have this issue

Comment: What do you mean? The form is on the website and there's a file field. The user clicks on "choose file" then submits the form. Then when the admin receives the filled out form, and downloads the file, the file is corrupt. However if I go to the "files" folder via ftp and download the file it is not corrupt (as indicated in the post above).